# How in RecyclerView perform scroll item with some position to top?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview, that have LinearLayoutManager and in it `reverseLayout=true`. How can I scroll item with some position to the top of the screen? Regular `recyclerView.scrollToPosition` or `layoutManager.scrollToPosition` didn't work, because item scrolled by that way displayed at the bottom of list and under the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

`linearLayoutManager!!.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0)`

Comment: Thank for answer, but it's method also scrolingl item to bottom edge

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(recyclerView.getChildCount());
```

or

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(list.size());
```

**Edit**

in your adapter you can check your current position, if you reach desired position you can scroll recyclerView to particulate position using interface

Comment: I don't need last item displaying in the top. For example, I have 40 items in list. What I need is when I scroll to 20 element it will be scrolled on the top.

Comment: How can I did it?

Answer (score 0):

`recyclerView.layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0)`

In your question you don't reference the recyclerview's `layoutmanager` but instead reference both the `recylcerview` and `layoutmanager` individually.

You much call `recylcerview.layoutmanager`

Comment: It would help readers if you added further explanation to your answer so they could see the value in your answer compared to the other solution choices. Use [edit] to improve your answer.

Comment: Edited answer, my apologies

Comment: Thank you for answer, but if you attached layoutManager to recyclerView I dont't see difference between calling scroll from layoutManager by recyclerView's object or by itself, because it is same layoutManagers